# jQuery selector only selects last id at the end of php loop result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

Pardon me for asking this question again because previous question not totally solves my problem. So let's begin. I am fetching data from database where I use foreach loop to display them. It works okay and displays what I wanted but the issue is with

`<div id="uploader<?php echo $value['id']?>">Upload</div>`.

What I am doing here is concat the id value with id from database and it prints okay like this.

- uploader1
- uploader2
- uploader3

Now I use this jquery code to select all the ids and display each uploader for every loop.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("[id*=fileuploader]").uploadFile({
    url:"YOUR_FILE_UPLOAD_URL",
    fileName:"myfile"
  });
});
```

The code runs with no errors in console but what I found is that it only selects the last result of the loop. So the upload button now is only showing on the last result not in all. Can you give me some directions to solve this? Thanks

Comment: my guess you are replacing not appending

Comment: what do you mean by that? Can you pls expand?

Comment: you get the values from start to finish but after getting second the first is overriden and so on until you are left with just the last one

Comment: @guradio, yes that's it. I am stuck with this.

Comment: try `$.each` something like `$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("[id*=fileuploader]").each($(this).uploadFile({
    url:"YOUR_FILE_UPLOAD_URL",
    fileName:"myfile"
  }));
});`

Comment: @NishanthMatha, I tried but I got an error saying this.uploadFile is not a function

Comment: and this `jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: b.call is not a function`

Comment: $(document).ready(function($) { 
  $("[id*=fileuploader]").each(function(){
  $(this).uploadFile({ url:"YOUR_FILE_UPLOAD_URL", fileName:"myfile" })  
  }); 
});

Comment: @user5200704, no errors in console but the file upload won't show up.

Comment: is the script capable of multiple instances on the same page?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qdj3kx7v/

Comment: @user5200704, That one works. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your filename:

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
$("[id*=fileuploader]").each(function(i,v){
  $(v).uploadFile({ url:"YOUR_FILE_UPLOAD_URL", fileName:"myfile"+i })
 });
});
```